# Seach and find value based on value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro that will search a specific column.

**Here are the steps:**
1. user enters a number into the cell and then executes the macro.
2. based on the value of what the user has entered, the macro will find the text in a column.

I got everything to work pretty well except I don't know how to define the value of the cell that the user enters. Any help here would be appreciated.

```
Sheets("New Version ").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Sheets("PN_List").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    'below is where I struggle
    Selection.Find(What:=(""), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the user enters a number into cell B4, then you just have to adjust your code into:

```
Selection.Find(What:=Range("B4").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways.

**Number1:**

Module based: (code in module)

```
Sub Sample()

Dim search_range as Range, search_value as Range, _
    lastcell as Range, foundcell as Range
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("PN_List")
Set search_range = ws.Range("I1", ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set lastcell = search_range.Cells(search_range.Cells.Count)
Set search_value = Thisworkbook.Sheets("New Version").Range("B4")

Set foundcell = search_range.Find(What:=search_value, After:=lastcell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then foundcell.Activate Else Msgbox "Not Found"

End Sub
```

**Number2:**

Worksheet Event based. (code in Sheet)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)

Dim search_range as Range, search_value as Range, _
    lastcell as Range, foundcell as Range
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("PN_List")
Set search_range = ws.Range("I1", ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set lastcell = search_range.Cells(search_range.Cells.Count)
Set search_value = Thisworkbook.Sheets("New Version").Range("B4")

If Not Intersect(Target, search_value) Is Nothing Then
query = Msgbox("Search data?", vbYesNo)
If query = 7 Then Exit Sub
Set foundcell = search_range.Find(What:=search_value, After:=lastcell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then foundcell.Activate Else Msgbox "Not Found"

End Sub
```

The first one you enter data in `B4` then run the macro.
The second one fires every time you change value in `B4`.
A msgbox will appear asking if you want to search the data entered.

Hope this helps.